# Fastest Way To Filter A Pandas Dataframe Using A List

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame such as:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     A
1     2     B
2     6     A
3     5     C
4     9     C
5     3     A
6     5     B
```

And multiple lists such as:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 4]
list_2 = [3, 8]
list_3 = [5, 6, 7, 9]
```

I can update the value of `col2` depending on whether the value of `col1` is included in a list, for example:

```
for i in list_1:
    df.loc[df.col1 == i, 'col2'] = 'A'

for i in list_2:
    df.loc[df.col1 == i, 'col2'] = 'B'

for i in list_3:
    df.loc[df.col1 == i, 'col2'] = 'C'
```

However this is very slow. With a dataframe of 30,000 rows, and each list containing approx 5,000-10,000 items, it can take a long time to calculate, especially compared to other pandas operations. Is there a better (faster) way of doing this?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `isin` with `np.select` here:

```
df['col2'] = (np.select([df['col1'].isin(list_1),
                         df['col1'].isin(list_2),
                         df['col1'].isin(list_3)]
                    ,['A','B','C']))
```

With `Map`:

```
d = dict(zip(map(tuple,[list_1,list_2,list_3]),['A','B','C']))
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map({val: v for k,v in d.items() for val in k})
```

---

```
   col1 col2
0     1    A
1     2    A
2     6    C
3     5    C
4     9    C
5     3    B
6     5    C
```

Answer (score 4):

You can first convert the lists to dicts and then map to col1.

```
d1 = {k:'A' for k in list_1}
d2 = {k:'B' for k in list_2}
d3 = {k:'C' for k in list_3}

df['col2'] = (
    df.col1.apply(lambda x: d1.get(x,x))
    .combine_first(df.col1.apply(lambda x: d2.get(x,x)))
    .combine_first(df.col1.apply(lambda x: d2.get(x,x)))
)
```

If there is no duplicates in the lists, you can make it even faster by merging them to a single dict:

```
d = {**{k:'A' for k in list_1}, 
     **{k:'B' for k in list_2}, 
     **{k:'C' for k in list_3}}
df['col2'] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: d.get(x,x))
```

Comment: I've used map at first but if the value of col1 doesn't exist in the dict, map will return an nan, using get will make sure the value stays the same.

Comment: Awesome answer :) +1

Comment: Thank you, 3,400 times faster than my existing method :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest iterating through your lists with a dictionary using conditional updating:

```
# Create your update dictionary
col_dict = {
    "A":[1, 2, 4],
    "B":[3, 8],
    "C":[5, 6, 7, 9]
}

# Iterate and update
for key, value in col_dict.items():
  # key is the col name; value is the lookup list
  df["col2"] = np.where(df["col1"].isin(value), key, df["col2"])
```

There is a concern of overwriting values – since a row can technically match multiple lists. How those updates are reconciled is not obvious.

If rows don't match multiple keys, consider a dynamic programming approach where a running index of "unmatched" rows are used for each iteration, updating as your proceed so that the number of rows you're iterating through are fewer with each iteration.

Comment: Thank you, 3,400 times faster than my existing method :)

Comment: Sweet! @Alan – how many seconds for the whole operation? _out of curiousity_

Comment: Previously, using my for loop method on a dataset on 2,700 rows, it took 3.471s to calculate. Using this method, it took 0.0009923s. A massive difference especially if the dataset has more than a few thousand rows. The other answers above all had a similar speed so I imagine they're all using the same underlying principles. Thanks again :)